# sync EBS volumes via S3

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, synchronization

I am looking to have multiple Amazon EC2 instances use the same data store.  Amazon does not condone mounting an S3 Bucket as a file system, so I am trying to avoid this solution.  Is there a way to synchronize an EBS volume with S3 or would it be best to use rsync and cron?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to have the files locally available from within EBS? What if instead you served them to yourself via CloudFront, and restricted the permissions so that only your instances (or only your Security Group) could see the files?

Come Fall 2015 you'll be able to use Elastic File Storage (EFS) for this. But until then, I would suppose the next best thing is to use the AWS command-line to sync down from S3 to your volume:

```
aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket/my/folder /mnt/my-ebs/
```

After the initial run, that sync command is surprisingly fast. So from there you could just cron it to run hourly or so?